# localeCompare() strange behavior on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, string, cross-browser, mobile-browser

localeCompare() is supposed to return (-1, 0, or 1), however, the following code returns '1' on my PC browser Chrome 53 (as expected), but '-8' on my cell phone's browser Samsung Internet for Android 4.0, which is supposed to be a modern brwoser!

```js
var b = "aZ";
var a= "ab"
var res = b.localeCompare(a);
document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML =res;
```

```html
<label id="alert">Ret</label>
```

Also fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/4a3rwem1/5/

Any alternative (maybe more comprehensive) solution for comparing strings in JS?

Comment: Your browser is based on [Servo](https://servo.org/), you can report an issue for this on [Github](https://github.com/servo/servo/issues), as `localeCompare` should apparently be supported in Servo.

Comment: Thanks @adeneo, I did!

Answer (score 0):

You could use smaller or greater sign to compare strings, like [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Sorting_with_map) suggest

```
+(a > b) || +(a === b) - 1
```

```js
var a = "ab",
    b = "aZ",
    aa = a.toLowerCase(),
    bb = b.toLowerCase(),
    res = +(a > b) || +(a === b) - 1;

console.log(res);
```

Comment: it would still be wrong.  -8 < 0  &  1 > 0.  I've just tested on my S7, and using Samsung's browser does indeed return -8.  Easy solutuon use Chrome on Samsung, or send a bug report to Samsung & hope for the best.

Comment: where do you get the 8?

Comment: What do you mean?, OP's question ->  `but -8 on my cell phone's browser`

Comment: Thanks both. I tested this. @Nina, that doesn't work properly. Consider this: https://jsfiddle.net/4a3rwem1/8/

Comment: you are right, you need to convert both strings for comparison to lower case first. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4a3rwem1/9/)

Comment: @NinaScholz, well, unfortunately, those are IDs, so I can't! thanks for your time though. It's interesting that in 2016, still some browsers have problems with this!

Comment: if you have numbers, why do you not use the numbers for comparison? even if they contain letters, you could parse it with `parseInt(value, 36)` to get a number.

Comment: I don't. Those are Firebase IDs (https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html)